# How to reorder a List?

Tags: android, http, web-applications

I have created a List by

```
List<NameValuePair> infoMap = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
URLEncodedUtils.parse(infoMap, new Scanner(Info), encoding);
```

But the **infoMap** contains a lot of information of which i only need a couple of values.

How can i create a new List which contains only the needed keys and its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to create a new list, and are very silent about the criteria of deciding whether an item should be the part of your result list or not, the simplest thing i can think of is

```
private List<NameValuePair> getUsefulList(final List<NameValuePair> baseList)
{
    final List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (final NameValuePair item : baseList)
    {
        if (isUseful(item.getName()))
            list.add(item);
    }
    return list;
}

private boolean isUseful(String name)
{
    return [... decision based on your criteria ...];
}
```

with these methods you can create your new list:

```
final List<NameValuePair> resultList = getUsefulList(baseList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isNeeded(Strnig name){
  //check here if you need this key
  return true;
}

List<NameValuePair> infoMap = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
...
List<NameValuePair> realInfoMap = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
for(NameValuePair val:infoMap){
  if(isNeeded(val.getName())){
    realInfoMap.add(val); 
  }
}

URLEncodedUtils.parse(realInfoMap, new Scanner(Info), encoding);
```